# How do I retrieve lines in a cell that consists of a certain text I want?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large list of usergroups and their respective usernames. Now, I'd liked to filter them even more. The usergroups for each user are ALL in one cell (username - usergroups), so that means there are maybe 10-15 usergroups in a single cell. I only want lines that consists of "WTS", and then placing the usergroups lines consisting of "WTS" into a new cell.

How do I go about doing this?

Example Data:

User Groups
1    WTS_A, 
     BTS_B, 
     WTS_C,

I want WTS_A and WTS_C.

Comment: Consider adding some example data

Comment: I added some example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question, I suggest a 2 step solution.

**Step 1** - Use Text to Columns feature in Excel and convert your single column text to multiple columns. Use Space and Comma both as delimiters.

**Step 2** - Use a custom VBA function to join only the intended cells into a single cell delimited by Comma.

After you are done with Text To Columns process, press ALT + F11 on the sheet to open the VBA Editor. From the Insert Menu Insert Module. A Module1 shall get created and its code editor shall open. If not double click Module1 in left pane to open its code editor.

Paste the following code into the same.

```
Public Function TXTJOIN(argument1 As Range)      'Accept input range
   result = ""
   colcounter = argument1.Columns.Count
   rowcounter = argument1.Rows.Count
   If rowcounter > 1 Then
        TXTJOIN = CVErr(xlErrValue)  'If row counter > 1 return #VALUE! Error
        Exit Function
   End If

   If colcounter > 255 Then
        TXTJOIN = CVErr(xlErrValue)  'If col counter > 255 return #VALUE! Error
        Exit Function
   End If


        For Each element In argument1
            If Left(element, 3) = "WTS" And Len(element) > 3 Then
                result = result & element & ","
            End If
        Next element

        If result = "" Then
            TXTJOIN = result
        Else
            TXTJOIN = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
        End If
End Function
```

This creates a custom TXTJOIN function to check for starting String as "WTS" and join all such columns delimited by Comma

Save and exit VBA editor. Back to the worksheet, now go to the extreme right column and enter this function specifying the column range applicable. Copy or drag it down along the length of the applicable rows. You should get the intended string in the respective cells. Copy only the values elsewhere and delete rest of the columns to clean up the sheet.

You shall get #VALUE! Error from this function in  situations like.

- You pass a multi dimensional array to it e.g. A1:D12
- You pass more than 255 columns range to it.
- You pass multiple rows array to it e.g. A1:A12

Let me know if this works for you.

Limitation - This assumes that userids are separated by either Space or Comma. If two are together without a comma or space, this function won't identify the two separately.

[image]

Comment: Had to edit some things because User & Groups is the column, and 1 and WTS_A, BTS_B, WTS_C is the rows of the User and Groups but this works well!

Answer (score 1):

You have two tasks: search for valid (interesting) data, and then format it.

## 1 Searching for a string:

Searching for a string such as WTS can be done with the functions Find or Search. They are both going to show you a numeric value when the string was found, like this:
FIND("WTS";A1) or SEARCH("WTS";A1)

Do this for the first row. Select the cell with your formula copy and then select the cells below it for all your data rows and paste. The formula will autoupdate itself to FIND("WTS";B1)...FIND("WTS";C1)...

I suggest manual filtering at this point to hide rows that give you error: #VALUE!

Just delete those rows that don't give you results.

## 2 Split the usergroups data:

When you have multiple entries in your cell delimited by a string (such as a dash "-"), select your cells and use Data -> Text to Columns -> Delimited -> Add your delimiter - choose Other and input a dash.

This will take your data and put it across multiple cells, like this
Usergroup1 Usergroup2 Usergroup3 ...

## 3 Bonus tip:

If you want to use the find or search function on the multiple cells that you have just split, do a concatenate of the cells into one cell (reverse basically the split) and then search on the concatenated values.
A7 = CONCATENATE(A1;A2;A3)
A8 = FIND("WTS";A7)